# How to send multple actions to store using redux-observable?

Tags: javascript, ajax, redux, rxjs, react-redux

What i am trying to do is:

1. Capture 'PRODUCTS_DISPLAY' action in reducer
2. Dispatch 'ON_PRODUCTS_FETCHNG' action
3. Load data via AJAX
4. If response is OK dispacth 'DONE_PRODUCTS_FETCHING' with payload from AJAX response
5. In case of AJAX error dispatch 'ON_PRODUCTS_FETCH_ERR'

and here is what i have already "coded":

```
const fetchProductsEpic = (action$, $store) =>
action$.ofType(PRODUCTS_DISPLAY)
    .do($store.dispatch({ type: 'ON_PRODUCTS_FETCHNG' }))
    .mergeMap(action => ajax.getJSON(`http://localhost:9000/products`)
        .map(response => productsFetchedAction(response))
        .catch(err => {
            $store.dispatch({ type: 'ON_PRODUCTS_FETCH_ERR', payload: err })
        })
    );
```

And i think I am kind of messed up with this code. I don't think that calling

```
.do($store.dispatch({ type: 'ON_PRODUCTS_FETCHNG' }))
```

manually is a good practice but i don't see any other way to do this.

Is there any way to code this epic more rationally and with best practices?

Comment: If you need to trigger 'ON_PRODUCTS_FETCHNG' when PRODUCTS_DISPLAY is emitted, you can use `switchMap` operator.

Comment: could you give me some example?